# Tailwind CSS centering a NexJS <Image /> component on a popup

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, next-images

I'm trying to get my MapBoxGL popup content to have some styling. I'm trying to get the text styling above the image to be on the left and then the image below to be centered on the popup. See below for image. I got here because I'm converting all of my  `<img>` components to next.js `<Image />` components and it seems to be a struggle. I wish the docs had more examples.

[image]

Anyways, here is my current code below. I've tried a multitude of things trying to figure it out. To my knowledge, I should have an outer `flex flex-col` parent, and then the text should be either `justify-start` or `items-start` and then the `div` parent of the `<Image />` should have `flex justify-center` or `justify-items-center` or something along those lines.

I also can't figure out why my popup is so much wider than my content when i only have `w-full` in the parent div and my `<Image />` is the only thing that specifies exact width.

Any and all help is appreciated!

```js
const popupContent = (
    <div className='test w-full h-full flex flex-col space-y-4'>
        {/*<div className='flex flex-row w-full h-full'>*/}
        <div className='flex flex-col items-start'>
            <Link
                href={`/listings/${listing.id}`}
                className="text-blue-500 hover:underline focus:outline-none">
                <h3>
                    {listing.title}
                </h3>
            </Link>
            <p>{listing.activity_type}</p>
            <p>{listing.mount_type}</p>
        </div>
        {/*<div className="relative w-full h-full">*/}
        <div className="relative w-3/4 h-full flex justify-center">
            {/*<div className="relative w-36 h-64">*/}
            <Image
                src={listing.primary_image_url}
                alt="Listing"
                // fill={true}
                object-Fit='fill'
                // width="100%"
                // className='justify-items-center'

                // className="object-cover w-full h-full"
                width='300'
                height='600'
                /*object-Fit='contain'
                fill={false}
                className='w-full'*/
            />
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: `mx-auto`on the image should solve the issue. That sets a margin auto on the horizontal axis. Or you can try to set the outer element as `flex flex-row justify-center`.

Comment: I added `flex flex-row justify-center` to the `div` containing the image and unfortunately, that didnt work :-/ any other ideas?

Comment: have you tried `mx-auto`?

Comment: holy $%$# it worked! `mx-auto` was the right thing to do. The `div` containing the `<Image />` component is now this: `<div className="relative w-3/4 h-full mx-auto">` . Go ahead and make your comment an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Comment: I'm happy it worked out. I was wondering already why it wouldn't work with mx-auto and had doubt about the relative positioning :D Have fun with your project ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting the image's parent `<div>` to `mx-auto` will sort out the issue. It stands for `margin: 0 auto` which will push the div into the middle on the vertical axis.